# How can I check whether a string index is in-bounds?

Tags: python

I'm doing homework and I have all except this last problem figured out. I can't seem to figure out how to get a character not to show up if it's inserted at a larger insertion point than the string has. This is the problem I'm working on:

> Write a program insert.py that simulates insert behavior on a string.
>
> The program takes three inputs: a character to be inserted, its position, and a string into which a character is to be inserted. The program prints the new version of the string. For example, if the arguments are: -, 2, below, then the program prints be-low. If a position passed to the program is outside of the bounds of the original string (in this case <0 or >5 -nothing would append on the end of below), then print the original string, without any changes (Note: an insert value of 0 OR the length of the string will add to the start or append to the end, i.e. T, 3, can will be canT; T, 0, can will be Tcan, and T, 4, can will be can).

This is what I have done so far:

```
C = input("Choose your charecter to insert. ")
P = int(input("Choose your character's position. "))
S = input("Choose your string. ")
st = S[:P] + C + S[P:]

print(st)
print(C, P, S)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just keep it simple. Check to see if the position is greater than the length of the word then just print the word, else proceed with your logic:

```
C = input("Choose your charecter to insert. ")
P = int(input("Choose your character's position. "))
S = input("Choose your string. ")

if P > len(S):
    print(S)
else:
    st = S[:P] + C + S[P:]

    print(st)
    print(C, P, S)
```

Comment: Now that I see that I should of thought of making it an if statement well thanks guys ill accept the answer when it lets me. Thanks for the help.
Though shouldn't the else be print(st) ubst if st = S[:P] + C + S[P:]

Comment: @David remember to also check for negative numbers, so `if 0 > P > len(S): print(S)`.

Answer (score 3):

Theres also this :)

```
result = list(S).insert(P, C)

if result:
    print(result)
else:
    print(S)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have found the answer you are looking for already. But here I would like to suggest my version.

```
C = input("Choose your charecter to insert. ")
P = int(input("Choose your character's position. "))
S = input("Choose your string. ")
print(S if P>len(S) else S[:P] + C + S[P:])
```

Answer (score -1):

We converted the string into a list and then change the value(update the string with inserting a character between a string).

```py
def anystring(string, position, character):
    list2=list(string)
    list2[position]=character
    return ''.join(list2)
```

Comment: This does *not* insert, it will overwrite: `anystring('hello', 1, 'x')` => `hxllo`