# How to put decimal after 2 digits in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, data-structures

Sample Input:

```
123453
```

Output:

```
12.3453
```

Regardless of the length of the string, I need to display the string with 2 decimal places at the beginning.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]. Try: `ans = lambda x: str(x)[:2]+'.'+str(x)[2:]
ans(12345)`

Comment: Print the first two characters of the input, then a decimal point, then the remainder of the input.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: here is the doc : https://docs.python.org/fr/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Whaf if the string has < 3 digits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting characters in strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050848/inserting-characters-in-strings-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add string in a certain position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5254445/2745495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few different ways. Some of these expect an int as input; some expect a string as input. I called the parameter `n` if it is expected to be an int, `s` if it is expected to be a string.

```py
def f1(n):
  while n >= 100:
    n = n / 10
  print(n)

def f2(n):
  t = 1
  q = n
  while q >= 100:
    q = q // 10
    t = t * 10
  r = n % t
  print('{}.{}'.format(q, r))

def f3(s):
  print('.'.join([s[:2], s[2:]]))

def f4(s):
  print(''.join([s[:2], '.', s[2:]]))

def f5(s):
  print(s[:2] + '.' + s[2:])

def f6(s):
  print('{}.{}'.format(s[:2], s[2:]))

def f7(s):
  f1(int(s))

def f8(n):
  f3(str(n))

for f in (f1, f2, f8):
  f(123453)

for f in (f3,f4,f5,f6,f7):
  f('123453')
```

Of course, you can replace `print(...)` with `return ...` if you want the function to return the string rather than print it. Note however that `print(n)` in function `f1` implicitly converts `n` from an int to a string; you can use `return str(n)` to explicitly convert `n` to a string before returning it.

Also note the important distinction between `f3,f4,f5,f6`, which expect any string as input, and `f1,f2`, which expect an int: the functions which expect a string will work with any string, even if that string doesn't represent a number. By contrast, function `f7` expects a string, but will immediately try to convert it to an int (with `int(s)`), so it will fail if the string doesn't represent a number.

Useful documentation:

- [Tutorial on input/output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html);
- [`str.join` string method to concatenate more than two strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join);
- [`str.format` string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).